# Will Threads Make My Game Run Consistently On Every Computer

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, timertask

Right now I'm using Java Swing timers to repaint my game etc.  On my gaming computer it runs at the speed I desire, but on the school computer is runs very slowly.  Sometimes it runs very slowly on my computer as well.

So would using threads make it consistent?  Could I keep the swing and do longs with current and past event times?  I tried that, but I was having a lot of trouble with it.  I've already done timertasks with the weapon delay, would that be consistent?

My swing stuff is very similiar to this: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/animation/

If you scroll down there is the threads part.

Thanks.

Comment: *"Right now I'm using Java Swing timers to repaint my game"* That statement worries me already. You should, realistically only have a single Timer which is responsible for updating the model state and triggering a repaint

Comment: I do have a single timer, bad grammar :P

Comment: The only benefit I see in using a `Thread` is it allows you to update the model state outside of the EDT.  The problem with this, is you need to someway to ensure that the UI is not updated while the model is being updated or some way to keep to models (one which you update and one which you paint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **not necessarily.** Threads likely have nothing to do with it.  In fact, depending on the number of threads the machines can run, the overhead to spin one up, and the actual parallel work you do, you may wind up performing *worse*.

Performance is subject not just to the quality of code, but to the quality of the machine running it.  So, it stands to reason that I'd expect a faster machine geared to gaming to perform better with a game than a school computer using lesser hardware.

That's not to say that your code couldn't use a refactoring, but in general, a machine that is better performing will be able to handle things better than one that...isn't.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the threads part, so is there no way to make the game run consistently on every machine?